# Most efficient way to save best performing TensorFlow model on validation set while training with thread for data loading

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

OK, it's so easy in Torch ML ;) and I am following indico example for threading to load the data- https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-input-part2-extensions/

So, for I found three ways, which I don't like and I am sure there is a better way.

1) Train and evaluate\validated on two different application\app\run- tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py and cifar10_eval.py

I don't like this one because I will waste resources i.e. GPUs where cifar10_eval.py will run. I can do this both from one file or application but don't like to save if model is not the best performing model!

2) Create validation model with weight sharing- tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py

Much better but I dont like the fact that I need to remember all the model parameters, I am sure there is a better way to share parameters in TensorFlow i.e. can I just copy the model and say it's for parameters sharing but input feeds are different?

3) The one currently I am doing is using tf.placeholder

But can't do threading things i.e. tf.RandomShuffleQueue with this approach. May be I don't know how to do via this approach.

So, how could I do, threading to load train data and do one epoch of training then use these weights and again do threading to load validation data and get the model performance?

Basically, I am saying multi-threads to load train and valid data and save the best peforming model. Example EXACTLY similar to imagenet multi GPU training in torch- https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable-sharing approach is probably the easiest way to do what you want.

Take a look at the ["Sharing Variables" tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html); by using tf.variable_scope() and tf.get_variable() you can reuse variables without having to manage the sharing explicitly. You can instead define the model in a function, call it with different arguments, but share the model variables between the two calls.

There are also convenience layers that wrap Tensorflow's variable management. One option is [Tensorflow Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim), which makes it easier to define some classes of models (especially convolutional models).

Comment: Thanks Peter, it's late but ya I have solved exactly the way you mentioned i.e. using tf.variable_scope() and tf.get_variable().